# How to make gulp work with files without extension

Tags: gulp, minimatch

I want to make gulp work with files without extension also. I tried to do it the following ways:

```
    function someTask() {
        return gulp.src('./src/**/*.{html,,xml,txt}')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
    }
    function someTask() {
        return gulp.src('./src/**/*.{html,!*,xml,txt}')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
    }
    function someTask() {
        return gulp.src('./src/**/*.{html,[^*],xml,txt}')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
    }
```

but I haven't got any results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still trying to find a better answer, but one route is to get all the files and then eliminate the extentions you don't want.  Like

```
var debug = require('gulp-debug');  // nice, will list all the files in the stream

return gulp.src(['./src/**/*', '!./src/**/*.{js,png}'])
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

So here `{js,png}` list the possible file extensions in your `src` directories you don't want.

Hopefully there is a better answer.

**[EDIT]: Maybe there is, try this:**

```
return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.{html,xml,txt}', './src/**/!(*\.*)'])
```

This part `./src/**/!(*\.*)` appears to match only files with no `.` in them, i.e., no extention.

Comment: Your pattern - ./src/**/!(*\.*) also includes directories. It is not desirable.

Comment: use the `nodir` option in that case.   See https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#options